# How can to get content of file from local computer in GXT GWT in server part? (com.sencha.gxt.ui.GXT)

Tags: java, gwt, file-upload, server, gxt

I have GXT GWT project (`<inherits name='com.sencha.gxt.ui.GXT'/>`). I need upload file from computer and get bytes array of file.

I wrote upload file in client part and all good, but I need added server part with get content of file, How can do it?
my client part:

```
public class FileUpload implements IsWidget {

    private static FileUploadUiBinder fileUploadUiBinder = GWT.create(FileUploadUiBinder.class);

    @UiTemplate("FileUpload.ui.xml")
    interface FileUploadUiBinder extends UiBinder<Component, FileUpload> {
    }

    @UiField
    FileUploadField uploadedFile;

    private FieldLabel label;

    @Override
    public Widget asWidget() {
        if (label == null) {
            label = (FieldLabel) fileUploadUiBinder.createAndBindUi(this);

            uploadedFile.addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) {
                    Info.display("File Changed", "You selected " + uploadedFile.getValue());

                    }
                });
            }
            return label;
        }
    }
```

and `FileUpload.ui.xml`:

```
        <!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
        <ui:UiBinder
                xmlns:form="urn:import:com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.form"
                xmlns:gxt="urn:import:com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client"
                xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
                xmlns="urn:import:com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.container"

                <form:FieldLabel>
                    <form:widget>
                        <form:FileUploadField ui:field="uploadedFile" name="metadataFile"/>
                    </form:widget>
                </form:FieldLabel>

        </ui:UiBinder>
```

so: I need added server part: How can to get bytes array (content of file) in server part? I need a example :) Maybe somebody give me link with working example? Help me, please.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately a lot of changes should be done to your code in order to show some example of how file data could be sent to server side. And I should mention that it's only one of possible solutions. Client-server request here goes to HttpServlet rather than through standard GWT RPC though. Here are my changes:

1) Changed FileUpload.ui.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:form="urn:import:com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.form"
    xmlns:gxt="urn:import:com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client"
    xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
    xmlns="urn:import:com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.container"
>
    <form:FormPanel>
        <form:FieldLabel>
            <form:widget>
                <form:FileUploadField ui:field="uploadedFile"
                    name="metadataFile" />
            </form:widget>
        </form:FieldLabel>
    </form:FormPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

2) Changed FileUpload.java:

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ChangeEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ChangeHandler;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiBinder;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiField;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiTemplate;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.IsWidget;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;
import com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.Component;
import com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.event.SubmitCompleteEvent;
import com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.form.FileUploadField;
import com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.form.FormPanel;
import com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.info.Info;

public class FileUpload implements IsWidget {

    private static FileUploadUiBinder fileUploadUiBinder = GWT.create(FileUploadUiBinder.class);

    @UiTemplate("FileUpload.ui.xml")
    interface FileUploadUiBinder extends UiBinder<Component, FileUpload> {
    }


    @UiField
    FileUploadField uploadedFile;

    private FormPanel formPanel;

    @Override
    public Widget asWidget() {
        if (formPanel == null) {
            formPanel = (FormPanel) fileUploadUiBinder.createAndBindUi(this);

            formPanel.setEncoding(FormPanel.Encoding.MULTIPART);
            formPanel.setMethod(FormPanel.Method.POST);
            formPanel.setAction("file.upload");  // This action should
            // point to servlet registered in WEB_INF/web.xml
            formPanel.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new SubmitCompleteEvent.SubmitCompleteHandler() {
                public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event) {
                    String resultHtml = event.getResults();
                    Info.display("Upload Response", resultHtml);
                }
            });

            uploadedFile.addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) {
                    Info.display("File Changed", "You selected " + 
                            uploadedFile.getValue());
                    formPanel.submit();  // It's better to do it by 
                    // clicking on submitting button or something. 
                }
            });
        }
        return formPanel;
    }
}
```

3) web.xml (only added parts, use your own package instead of `home.test.uploadtest`):

```
<... other servlet blocks ...>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>fileUploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>home.test.uploadtest.server.FileUploadServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>   

<... other servlet-mapping blocks ...>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>fileUploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/file.upload</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

4) FileUploadServlet.java (mostly dummy example of server-side operation):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

public class FileUploadServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        File tempDir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
        FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory(1000000, tempDir);
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        File target = null;
        try {
            try {
                List<?> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
                Iterator<?> it = items.iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    FileItem item = (FileItem) it.next();
                    if (item.isFormField()) {
                        throw new ServletException("Unsupported non-file property [" + 
                                item.getFieldName() + "] with value: " + item.getString());
                    } else {
                        target = File.createTempFile("temp_", ".data", tempDir);
                        item.write(target);
                        item.delete();
                        System.out.println("Temp file: " + target.getAbsolutePath());
                    }
                }
            } catch (ServletException e) {
                throw e;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(e);
            }
            response.getWriter().write("File length: " + target.length());
            response.getWriter().close();
        } finally {
            if (target != null && target.exists())
                target.delete();
        }
    }   
}
```

So as you can see there is a dependency to https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/

PS: I think that because of large size of code I might forget something. In this case just let me know.